# How to make datalabels of a few intersecting points display in a good way?

Tags: javascript, html, chart.js

No I have a line-chart with a few lines on it. These lines intersected in some points. Also I'm using chartjs-plugin-datalabels to label points on graphics.

The problem is: if i have a few points from different lines in one place, their labels also display in one place, which is bad. How can I make them look nice and readable?

You can see that problem in the second chart (point with "2 (...)"):
[image]

Didn't find anything in DOCs and I'm new to JS. So, I hope I'll get some help from you guys :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well Without seeing your code I must deduce how it would look like and how I would solve it.

Well I would:

1. Iterate over the data and look for crossing points
2. Create a "Dictionary" for the crossing points with the desired label

   - To create the labels for the crossing points I use an newline, but one could also use any other separator, like comma or so.
3. use the `formatter` function from the plugin to set the labels for the crossing point's

**Here a demo, how I would do this:**
*There are some comments in the code that mark the essential parts.*

```js
const data = {
    labels: ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'], 
    datasets: [{
        label: 'DS1',
        data: [{x:1, y: 1, v:'d1'}, {x:2, y: 2, v:'d1'}, {x:3, y: 4, v:'d1'}, {x:4, y: 3, v:'d1'}], 
     }, {
        label: 'DS2',
        data: [
            {x:1, y: 1, v:'d2'}, {x:2, y: 2, v:'d3'}, {x:3, y: 2, v:'d2'}, {x:4, y: 2, v:'d2'}], 
     }, {
        label: 'DS3',
        data: [{x:1, y: 1, v:'d3'}, {x:2, y: 2, v:'d3'}, {x:3, y: 5, v:'d3'}, {x:4, y: 5, v:'d3'}], 
     }],
};

// Helper to get all values into on array
let flatDatalist = data.datasets.map( entry => entry.data).flat();

// find all overlapping points
let overlappingEntries = flatDatalist.filter( (entry, index )=>{
    return flatDatalist.some((entryInner, indexInner) => index != indexInner && entry.x == entryInner.x && entry.y == entryInner.y)
})

// create an Array with new formated label for overlapping labels
let labelsForOverlappingEntries = overlappingEntries.reduce((prev, curr) => {
    let key = `${curr.x}__${curr.y}`;
    
    if(!prev[key]){
        prev[key] = `${data.labels[curr.x]}:${curr.v}`;
    } else {
          prev[key] = `${prev[key]}\n${data.labels[curr.x]}:${curr.v}`;
    }
    
    return prev;
 }, {});

const config = {
    type: 'line',
    data: data,
    plugins:[ChartDataLabels],
    options: {
        scales: {
          y: {
            min: 0,
            max: 6,
          }
        },
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        plugins: {
          datalabels: {
            align: 'end',
            anchor: 'end',
            offset: -1,
            formatter: function(v, ctx){
              // get a multiline label when needed
              let key = `${v.x}__${v.y}`;
              if(labelsForOverlappingEntries[key]){
                return labelsForOverlappingEntries[key];
              }
              return ctx.chart.data.labels[ctx.dataIndex] + ': '+ v.v;
            },
          }
        }
    }
};

new Chart(
    document.getElementById('chart'),
    config
);
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>  
<script src="
https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-datalabels@2.2.0/dist/chartjs-plugin-datalabels.min.js
"></script>
<div class="chart" style="height:184px; width:350px;">
    <canvas  id="chart" ></canvas>
</div>
```

> ***Disclaimer** I'm not sure if this is the best way, and it is maybe abit over engineered. Nevertheless it works, I hope you can use this, or atleast it helps to find your way.*